# Deactivate filtering if inputs comes with all in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, filtering

I am trying to filter my results

```
$students = \App\User::leftJoin('exam_places', 'exam_places.exam_place_no', '=', 'users.exam_place_id')
                   ->select(['exam_places.*',
                             'users.*',
                            ])
                    ->where('exam_places.id',$input['examplace'])
                    ->where('users.paymenet_method',$input['payment'])
                    ->where('users.payStatus',$input['status'])->get();
```

my inputs comes like this for examplace (all, 1,2,3,4,5) 
for paymentmethod(all,1,2,3,4,..)
for paystatus(0,1)

all my filtering method works however if user selects all as  my

```
$input[examplace]= all
```

where statement looks for

```
where('exam_places.id','all')
```

however I want to disable this statement if all selected.

I tried to add

```
if($input[examplace] !=='all') {
->where('exam_places.id',$input['examplace'])
}
```

it gave me error.

**Edit**: let me explain briefly what code I've tried

```
$students = \App\User::leftJoin('exam_places', 'exam_places.exam_place_no', '=', 'users.exam_place_id')
                   ->select(['exam_places.*',
                             'users.*',
                            ])
if($input['examplace'] !== 'all){
                    ->where('exam_places.id',$input['examplace'])
}
                    ->where('users.paymenet_method',$input['payment'])
                    ->where('users.payStatus',$input['status'])->get();
```

it gives me the error below [image]

so question is how can I deactivate my if statement if input comes as **all** ?

Comment: `if($input['examplace'] !=='all') `  add quotes?

Comment: this is not quote related error. I just forgot to add quotes to my question :)

Comment: 'it gave me error' How can I know what error you have? :)

Comment: explained with more details =)

Comment: Better now :) I know a possible sollution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add logical statements within chaining, you can`t do that without separating them
Try adding the statements sequentially:

```
$stmt = \App\User::leftJoin('exam_places', 'exam_places.exam_place_no', '=', 'users.exam_place_id')
                 ->select(['exam_places.*','users.*',]); //break here
if($input['examplace'] !== 'all'){
    $stmt->where('exam_places.id',$input['examplace']);
}
$stmt->where('users.paymenet_method',$input['payment'])
     ->where('users.payStatus',$input['status']);
$students = $stmt->get();
```

Comment: Isnt I suppose to write get() after select ?